# PM2 getting error while starting with json file

Tags: node.js, pm2

> Following is my json file. File name (**pm2-ecosystem.json**)

```
 {
            "apps" : [{
                "name"        : "Performance",
                "script"      : "server.js",
                "watch"       : false,
                "exec_mode"   : "cluster_mode",
                "instances"   : 4,
                "max_memory_restart" : "500M",
                "merge_logs": true,
                "env": {
                    "NODE_ENV": "development"
                },
                "env_production" : {
                    "NODE_ENV": "production"
                }
            }] 
}
```

And I am restarting it via following script in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "build-prod": "pm2 restart pm2-ecosystem.json --env production"
  },
```

I am getting error like this:

> 2019-03-19T02:49:21: PM2 error: Error: spawn /usr/local/bin/node
>   ENOENT PM2        |     at _errnoException (util.js:1024:11) PM2
>   |     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:192:19) PM2        |     at onErrorNT
>   (internal/child_process.js:374:16) PM2        |     at
>   _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11) PM2        |     at process._tickDomainCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9) PM2        |
>   2019-03-19T02:49:21: PM2 log: App name:Javelin-backend id:56
>   disconnected PM2        | 2019-03-19T02:49:43: PM2 log: App
>   [Javelin-backend:56] starting in -cluster mode- PM2        |
>   2019-03-19T02:49:43: PM2 error: Error: spawn /usr/local/bin/node
>   ENOENT PM2        |     at _errnoException (util.js:1024:11) PM2
>   |     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:192:19) PM2        |     at onErrorNT
>   (internal/child_process.js:374:16) PM2        |     at
>   _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11) PM2        |     at process._tickDomainCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9) PM2        |
>   2019-03-19T02:49:43: PM2 log: App name:Javelin-backend id:56
>   disconnected

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code if possible,

```
pm2.connect(function() {
  pm2.start({
    "script" : /* Path to your starting file */,   
    "exec_mode" : "cluster",
    "pmx" : false
  }, function(err, apps) {
    pm2.disconnect();
  });
})
```

Comment: Hi Owner, Thanks for reply.
Actually I am trying to start pm2 via json file. At local(MAC os) it is working fine. But It is not working on digital ocean server, while it is working with normal pm2 on the same. Basically, I have to put "max_memory_restart" because there are some memory leak in the nodejs. And somewhere I found, it will be removed if I use "max_memory_restart" value.

Thanks